# Log stash Date filter - pattern without year

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I have logs that I am parsing and the date does not contain the year which should be default current year.

The field that I get after grok etc  is 06/25 11:33:19.9 PM  and 06/25 11:33:19.9 PM etc

I am trying to use the date filter to change these to a date field type before sending to elastic search. I am using the date filter below

```
date {
match => ["timestamp", "MM/dd HH:mm:ss:S a"]
    target => "timestamp"
 }
```

But I am getting a  dateparsefailure. I'm i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"MM/dd HH:mm:ss:S a"` should be `"MM/dd HH:mm:ss.S a"`

Since your timestamp has AM/PM in it, instead of HH (hour of the day -- 0-23) you probably want K (0-11) or h (1-12).

If your dates do not have a year in them then logstash will guess, and sometimes it will guess wrong. See the date filter issues on github -- [137](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-date/issues/137), 100, and the long discussion of 51.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it. The issue was the  "S:" . I changed it to "S." and issue resolved. it selected current year as the year which is fine with me. Thanks